# Auto-fit all columns and find the last row and the last column that have data

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

I'd like to:

1. Make sure all the columns of an Excel worksheet are widened enough to fit the text in each row of the column; and
2. I'd like to find the last column and the last row that have data in that worksheet, i.e. the last non-empty row and the last non-empty column.

A cell that has a background color but no text would also be considered to be non-empty.

So, for instance, a worksheet like this:

[image]

Looks like this:

[image]

And the last data cell is reported as **D10** because it is the last **dirty** cell even though it has no text.

What VSTO methods/API will give me the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For determining a used range use Worksheet.UsedRange Property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

For autofit columns in this range use Range.AutoFit Method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofit-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
UsedRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1").usedrange
UsedRange.Columns.Autofit
```